# x86 assembly program stuck in a loop

Tags: assembly, x86

I am writing a x86 assembly program. For some reason my loop is getting stuck. I was wondering if anyone can help me figure out why je statement isnt being executed? If I put an output inside of second loop, it will output forever until crashing. So how come the je comparison is not firing properly?

;;Ignore compute_bs MACRO, it should not be relevant to my issue;;

Thanks

```js
interpolate_proc PROC NEAR32
 push ebp
 mov ebp, esp
 fldz
 mov cx, degree
 
 START_LOOP:
  mov eax, 0
  cmp cx, 0
  je END_LOOP
  mov dx,0

  fld1
  SECOND_LOOP:
   cmp dx, cx   ;<-- Not executing. even though inc dx
   je SECOND_END

   mov ebx, array
   fld REAL4 PTR x
   mov ax, 8
   mul dx
   add ebx, eax
   fld REAL4 PTR [ebx]
   fsubr
   fmul
   inc dx
   jmp SECOND_LOOP
   
  SECOND_END:
   output prompt
   mov ebx, array
   compute_bs ebx, cx
   mov temp, eax
   fld REAL4 PTR temp
   fmul
   fadd
   
  dec cx
  jmp START_LOOP 
  
 END_LOOP:
 
 compute_bs ebx, cx
 mov temp, eax
 fld REAL4 PTR temp
 fadd
 fstp REAL4 PTR temp
 mov eax, temp
 mov esp, ebp
 pop ebp
interpolate_proc ENDP
END
```

Comment: Austin, if the answer was useful you may click the checkmark to accept it.

Comment: You should learn to run your code under a debugger.  It would allow you to find these types of issues yourself quickly.

Comment: What do you recommend? I'm on Windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instruction

```
mul dx
```

multiplies `ax` by `dx` and places the 32-bit product in `dx:ax`, overwriting your operand in `dx`. So the loop test will fail.